# How to discover which users have access to which Lookup Tables

Tags: commcare

I have a lookup table in a project space that is not visible to all users. What is the best way to figure out which users have access to that lookup table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookup Tables can either be assigned to groups or locations. All users that are in that group or location have access to that table.

In order to find which groups and/or locations a Lookup Table is assigned to, you can view the table at this link:

https://www.commcarehq.org/a/YOUR_DOMAIN/fixtures/view_lookup_tables/

Then look for a column called `group 1` (or `group 2`, `group N`) or `location 1` (or `location 2`, `location N`). The value in this column will tell you which group or location that that Lookup Table is accessible to.